# HTTPS works only with Load Balancer DNS - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I have a problem with HTTPS configuration on AWS hope you can help.

What I already have:

1. EC2 - with Elastic IP, open ports [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GLoM.png) with security group.
2. Load Balancer attached to EC2 (with same security group as EC2).
3. SSL certificate from AWS (ACM)
4. **Domain** - "Transferred", From another service (not amazon) using just Elastic IP for DNS configurations. (Can this be the problem?)
5. Route53 - configured for **Domain** with AWS (SSL) and for IPV4 address I am using alias for Load Balancer.

How it works:

- EC2: Elastic IP and public DNS (are working only for **http**) as it should work I guess.
- LOAD BALANCER: Works and gives **HTTPS** and **HTTP** access just from DNS name.
- Route53(domain) - Works just for HTTP, every HTTPS request returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

How I explain this problem for myself (if there is problem please tell me)
So if **Domain** is redirecting from DNS settings to Elastic IP that's attached to EC2 there can not be SSL connection as I am using ACM for ssl certificate, that's when LOAD BALANCER comes for help to connect the **Domain** and **SSL**, but as in **Domain's** DNS there is not connection with LBS, AWS is not able to give the SSL just from **Route53** configurations?

*Is it going to fix the problem if I will change EC2's elastic ip in Domain DNS with Load Balancer's public DNS name?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the instance's Elastic IP as a DNS A record is exactly the cause of the problem.  The DNS record needs to point directly to the load balancer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, I believe it will solve the problem, as soon as I try to I will write back.

Answer (score 0):

Point the DNS to tge ELB CNAME and configure Nginx/Apache as X-Proto Forward so that server can forward https redirection requests to load Balancer. If check AWS documentation you will easily able to do this.